# Refactoring a php function at Laravel Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-9

I have a method at a Model like this:

```
public function questionOwner($id)
    {
        if (auth()->user()->id == $id) {
           return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Now I wanted to refactor this function so I tried this:

```
public function queOwner($id)
    {
        return !! auth()->user()->id == $id;
    }
```

So if `auth()->user()->id` was not equals to `$id`, then it should return **`false`** because of `!!` but I don't know why it always return TRUE!

So if you know what's going wrong here and how can I refactor this function, please let me know, thanks...

Comment: `!!` does nothing here, because the result of `==` is always a boolean.

Comment: Use `!==` instead, ie: `return auth()->user()->id !== $id`

Comment: As others said - remove `!!` - these are pointless here.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski When to use `!!` ?

Comment: try with ternary :  ````return auth()->user()->id == $id ? true : false;````

Answer (score 2):

Maybe that's what you mean?

```
public function queOwner($id)
{
    return auth()->user()->id === $id;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you could do in two ways

```
    public function questionOwner($id)
    {

        return Auth::user()->id == $id
    }
```

or

```
    public function questionOwner($id)
    {
       return Auth::user()->id==$id?true:false;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
// Pre-requirement
    function auth() {
        return new class { 
           public function user() {
               return new class {
                   public $id = 15;
               };
           }
        };
    }

// Client code
class A {
    public function queOwner($id)
    {
        // According to the priority https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php
        // double !! here implies only the left side of the comparison, so
        // expression here is "return (!(! auth()->user()->id)) == $id)
        // Comparison here performs after the type juggling.
        // For example:
        // "!(! 15)" -> "not (not 15)" -> "not 0" -> true
        // if $id is equal to any non-zero integer number, it will be interpreted as true,
        // Hence, if auth()->user()->id is not 0 and $id is not 0, this statement always returns true, otherwise - false.
        return !! auth()->user()->id == $id;
    }
}


// Examples
var_dump((new A())->queOwner(15)); // true
var_dump((new A())->queOwner(13)); // true
var_dump((new A())->queOwner(0)); // false
```

A full example could be found here: https://php.band/D2pzfPA2t

So, to avoid such a situation, use [Strict comparison (Identical)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) or (better) [strict typing](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.declarations.php#language.types.declarations.strict).